# React Hook Form with Material UI Field Array to Have Their Own Value

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, state, react-hook-form

I am currently having a problem when using react-hook-form with MUI.

**Scenario**

I am building a product upload form so that users can select categories of the product. There are main categories and each main category has its sub-categories. I only need to collect sub-categories data. Users can choose up to 3 categories, so I used react-hook-form filed array.

**What I am trying to achieve**

When a user clicks ADD CATEGORY button, the dropdown menu will show up to select the main category. If the user selects one of the main categories, its list of sub-categories will show up at the bottom as a Toggle Button. As a result, I will collect an array of sub-categories that the user selected.

**Problem**

After the first selection, when the user tries to select another category from the dropdown menu, the previous list of sub-categories changes to the current sub-categories. I want each field to have its state and value. How should I fix this problem?

If there is a better approach when dealing with forms like this, please feel free to give me some advice. Thank you!

[Link To CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-feather-gixm5y)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not saving on the field its values...

```
onChange={(e) => setSelectedId(e.target.value)}
```

You're using the Select component to update your App local state, then using it to find the category from which to render your options...

```
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
  const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find(
    (category) => category.id === selectedId
  );
```

You're appending fields, but using the same state and selected category each time:

```
selectedCategory.subCategories.map(...
```